# Coequalizer in category of dg-algebras

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, model-categories, differential-graded-algebras

It is known that there is a model structure on category of dg algebras (non-commutative over arbitrary commutative ring). In particular it is complete and co-complete category. My question is how to construct limits and co-limits. I'm especially interested in co-equalizers.

Comment: That's extremely complicated. There's no explicit way of doing it. The existence of such colimits is via general categorical results which, in my experience, are impossible to trace back in order to recover a sensible construction.

Comment: @Fernando is it also complicated to construct equalizers when the commutative ring is a field?.

Comment: @VictorTC equalizers (and limits in general) are easy. The equalizer of two maps is just the kernel of the difference.

Comment: @Fernando I apologize, I meant the coequalizer when the commutative ring is a field.

Comment: @VictorTC coequalizers are very complicated in general. I don't think that any property of the ground ring could simplify things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general bit of category theory that was applied to 
ring spectra in EKMM ([83] on my website) and I'll refer
to that for details.  Unless I am missing something, the
discussion surely specializes just as well to dg algebras over a 
commutative ring $R$.  I'll outline the recipe it gives
for constructing all colimits of dg $R$-algebras as reflexive 
coequalizers in the category $Ch_R$ of chain complexes over $R$.

The free graded $R$-algebra functor induces a free dg $R$-algebra 
functor on $Ch_R$. That gives a monad $T$ on $Ch_R$ whose algebras 
are the dg $R$-algebras.  This monad preserves reflexive coequalizers 
by Prop. 7.2, p. 47.  Therefore, by Lemma 6.6, p. 46, if $g\colon B\to C$ 
is a reflexive coequalizer of maps $e,f\colon A\to B$ in $Ch_R$ such that 
$A$ and $B$ are $T$-algebras and $e$ and $f$ are maps of $T$ algebras, then
$C$ has a unique structure of $T$-algebra such that $g$ is a 
map of $T$-algebras, and $g$ is the coequalizer of $e$ and $f$
in the category of $T$-algebras.  Now all colimits in the
category of $T$-algebras are constructed from just such 
reflexive coequalizer diagrams in $Ch_R$, as shown in the
proof that the category of $T$-algebras is cocomplete given in
Prop. 7.4, p. 49.